# Camera looking around with mouse - Unity, C#

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, camera

I am building a script in C# for camera logic in Unity, the camera is supposed to follow the player (a 3rd person character) around and the user should be able to look around using the mouse, so far everything works fine (the following logic and looking around on the horizontal axis) the problem is I can't get the camera to move along the vertical axis, left and right are fine but up and down are not working.

This is the C# script:

```
public class PlayerFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PlayerTransform;

    private Vector3 _cameraOffset;

    [Range(0.01f, 1.0f)]
    public float SmoothFactor = 0.5f;

    public bool LookAtPlayer = false;

    public bool RotateAroundPlayer = true;

    public bool RotateMiddleMouseButton = true;

    public float RotationsSpeed = 5.0f;

    public float CameraPitchMin = 1.5f;

    public float CameraPitchMax = 6.5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _cameraOffset = transform.position - PlayerTransform.position;
    }

    private bool IsRotateActive
    {
        get
        {
            if (!RotateAroundPlayer)
                return false;

            if (!RotateMiddleMouseButton)
                return true;

            if (RotateMiddleMouseButton && Input.GetMouseButton(2))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update methods
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (IsRotateActive)
        {

            float h = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationsSpeed;
            float v = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationsSpeed;

            Quaternion camTurnAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(h, Vector3.up);

            Quaternion camTurnAngleY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(v, Vector3.up);

            Vector3 newCameraOffset = camTurnAngle * camTurnAngleY * _cameraOffset;

            // Limit camera pitch
            if (newCameraOffset.y < CameraPitchMin || newCameraOffset.y > CameraPitchMax)
            {
                newCameraOffset = camTurnAngle * _cameraOffset;
            }

            _cameraOffset = newCameraOffset;

        }

        Vector3 newPos = PlayerTransform.position + _cameraOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, SmoothFactor);

        if (LookAtPlayer || RotateAroundPlayer)
            transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're applying both your rotations about the axis Vector3.up — did you mean to pitch around transform.right for your vertical movement?

Comment: I tried `transform.right` and it didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is never enough information to diagnose a problem. Remember to always include the specific symptoms observed — they help lead users to uncovering the next piece of the solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to get more specific, my script is there and the only problem I am facing is that the Y axis of the mouse is not moving, the camera is moving horizontally but not vertically

Comment: Sounds like your pitch min/max are too tight, so the pitch limit check always triggers and undoes the vertical rotation. You can verify this by stepping through your routine with a debugger to see exactly what path it takes and where the vertical motion gets discarded.